# How to get the Message from IStatusLineManager in RCP?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have scenario where I have to show more status on single status bar.When I am trying to read the message and combine new message(append).I am not able to get the existing message using IStatusLineManager.

Comment: There is no way to get the existing message.

Comment: So is there any way to bring multiple Status line messages using RCP?

Comment: `IStatusLineManager` is a `IContributionManager` so you can add your own contributions to it. This is what text editors do to add things like the line/column number display.

Answer (score 0):

```
IStatusLineManager statusline=w.getStatusLineManager();
statusline.update(true);
StatusLineContributionItem geographicalStatusLineItem = null;
            for (IContributionItem item : statusline.getItems()) {
                if (item instanceof StatusLineContributionItem) {
                    geographicalStatusLineItem = (StatusLineContributionItem) item;
                }
            }
         // create the status line
            if (geographicalStatusLineItem == null) {
                geographicalStatusLineItem = new StatusLineContributionItem("SelfTimeContributionItem");
                geographicalStatusLineItem.setText("Test");
                statusline.add(geographicalStatusLineItem);
            }

            geographicalStatusLineItem.setText("Test");
```